# Where can I find an open source component-based game?

Tags: component-based

Check that link:
[Evolve Your Hierarchy](http://cowboyprogramming.com/2007/01/05/evolve-your-heirachy/)

I'm interested in that kind of game development, and the theory looks nice! But I want taking a look in the source code of some game developed following that methodology. It will be good if it's simplistic (or even educational!), and better if it's coded C++ or C#. Thanks!

Comment: I think this question will only generate a list of responses, without one being more correct than the next. Making it not a good fit for a QA site. Just look around at some of the entity/component frameworks, many of them have simple example games. i.e. http://gamadu.com/artemis/demos.html

Comment: @Byte56 Wow, it's so common to find source code for that kind of game? If needed, can you change that post to community wiki?

Comment: There are a lot of games that use component based systems, plenty of open source ones too. I don't have the power to create a community wiki, though I don't think this question will qualify. Do a bit of research and you'll find what you need.

Answer (score 1):

As Byte56 points out, there are a lot of articles on the web discussing this topic.  It's been a highly debated and discussed game developer topic for years now and probably will be for more years to come.

The reason why its still such a hot ticketed concept is because there really isn't a tried and true **roadmap** that describes how to manage, store, and relate entities and components.  Just when you think you have a strategy on how you'll go about it, the next article you read may approach it from an entirely different angle, leaving you proposing some mixin or alternative all together.

My advice is to start small and simple.  Don't try to design an Entity Component System with all the bells and whistles, just concentrate on a just a few specific features you want to try and explore.  Tweak the design and don't be afraid to rewrite it if needed.  Such a system can quickly evolve and as you add more behaviors and features, you'll find the need for more and more bells here and there which often require tweaks or even major changes.